# How can I stop the LEGO Cargo train 60052 wheels from skidding on track?

Tags: piece-information, trains

I have the Cargo train 60052, it's only around a year old and lately I've found on starting it (on both straight and curved track pieces) it isn't moving, the wheels seem to skid on the tracks and I have to give it a little nudge to get it going, even then it tends to stop further down.

I'm wondering if this is an issue with the tracks or the wheels?

I have taken them off and tried wiping them and 'rotating' them but no luck. I have looked online but haven't found any resolution, can anyone help me? :)

Comment: Can you check if the motor bogie's wheels still have rubber bands on them? These bands are giving the train traction - you might want to either clean the wheels or find new rubber bands to put around the wheel to see if this helps.

Answer (score 5):

Replace or reset the rubber bands on the wheels. This trick works on the 80s era trains so should work here too.

Comment: If you can't find any LEGO rubber bands, normal hair rubber bands will work too - cosmetic stores sell a bunch of different sizes to choose from!